# Alinear labels en gráfico Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Estoy generando una gráfica de Highcharts, pero algunos detalles no logro solucionarlos.

- Los labels se confunden unos con otros.
- Los labels de los 2 spline de color rojo mostrarlos horizontalmente no verticalmente y solo en la posición 0 de la izquierda.

La gráfica debo dejarla lo mas parecida posible a:

[image: Gráfico]

Este es el código:

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
   chart: {
     zoomType: 'x'

     // ,styledMode: true
   },
   title: {
     text: 'Indicador'
   },

   subtitle: {
     text: 'Subtitulo'
   },
   xAxis: {
     title: {
       text: 'Titulo 1'
     }
     /*,
         min: 20,
         max: 40,
         scrollbar: {
           enabled: true
         },*/

   },
   yAxis: {
     title: {
       text: 'Titulo 2'
     }
   },
   legend: {
     layout: 'vertical',
     align: 'right',
     verticalAlign: 'middle' 
   },

   plotOptions: {
     spline: {
       dataLabels: {
         enabled: true,
         formatter: function() {
           return 1;
         },
         y: -30 //separacion del indicador
       }
     },
     series: {
       label: {
         connectorAllowed: false
       },
       dataLabels: {
         enabled: true,
         formatter: function() {
           var color = '';
           var serie = this.series.name;
           if (serie == '2017-Rendimiento') {
             color = 'purple';
           } else if (serie == '2018-Rendimiento') {
             color = 'green';
           } else if (serie == '2017-RendimientoF') {
             color = 'Blue';
           } else if (serie == '2018-RendimientoF') {
             color = 'Brown';
           } else {
             if (this.x == 0) { //si posicion es 0 muestre spline con color
               color = 'red'; //color spline
             } else {
               color = 'white';
             }
           }

           return '<span style="color:' + color + '">' + this.y + '</span>';
         },
         align: 'center',
         color: 'black',
         rotation: -90
       }
       /*,
             pointStart: 2010*/

     }
   },

   series: [{
     name: '2017-Rendimiento',
     data: [275, 270, 276, 265, 271, null, 270, 271, 255, 260, 255, 262],
     color: 'purple'
   }, {
     name: '2018-Rendimiento',
     data: [260, 265, null, 270, 263, 266, 264, 264, 254, 264, 254, 264],
     color: 'green',
     lineWidth: 4
   }, {
     name: '2017-RendimientoF',
     data: [210, 222, null, 222, 220, 210, 210, 210, 223, 210, 218, 225],
     color: 'blue',
     height: 5
   }, {
     name: '2018-RendimientoF',
     data: [null, 225, 225, 225, 225, 225, 235, 245, 225, 215, 215, 229],
     color: 'brown',
     lineWidth: 4
   }, {
     type: 'spline',
     name: '2018-Meta Core',
     data: [267, 267, 267, 267, 267, 267, 267, 267, 267, 267, 267, 267],
     marker: {
       lineWidth: 2,
       lineColor: 'red',
       fillColor: 'red',
       symbol: 'circle'
     },
     color: 'red'
   }, {
     type: 'spline',
     name: '2017-Meta Core',
     data: [220, 220, 220, 220, 220, 220, 220, 220, 220, 220, 220, 220],
     marker: {
       lineWidth: 2,
       lineColor: 'red',
       fillColor: 'red',
       symbol: 'circle'
     },
     color: 'red'
   }],

   responsive: {
     rules: [{
       condition: {
         maxWidth: 500
       },
       chartOptions: {
         legend: {
           layout: 'horizontal',
           align: 'center',
           verticalAlign: 'bottom'
         }
       }
     }]
   }

 });
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<div id="container" class="chart"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Highcharts no tiene predefinida una funcion para "separar" las etiquetas cuando estas se superponen. Lo unico que queda por hacer es situarlas de manera dinámica. Te preparé un ejemplo donde las etiquetas se agregan de manera dinámica luego de que el gráfico se carga, aquí te lo dejo:

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
   chart: {
     zoomType: 'x',
     events: {
     load: function() {
            loadLabels(this)
            }
        }
   },
   title: {
     text: 'Indicador'
   },

   subtitle: {
     text: 'Subtitulo'
   },
   xAxis: {
     title: {
       text: 'Titulo 1'
     }
     /*,
         min: 20,
         max: 40,
         scrollbar: {
           enabled: true
         },*/

   },
   yAxis: {
     title: {
       text: 'Titulo 2'
     }
   },
   legend: {
     layout: 'vertical',
     align: 'right',
     verticalAlign: 'middle' 
   },

   series: [{
     name: '2017-Rendimiento',
     data: [275, 270, 276, 265, 271, null, 270, 271, 255, 260, 255, 262],
     color: 'purple',
     dataLabels: {
   y: -30
     }
   }, {
     name: '2018-Rendimiento',
     data: [260, 265, null, 270, 263, 266, 264, 264, 254, 264, 254, 264],
     color: 'green',
     lineWidth: 4
   }, {
     name: '2017-RendimientoF',
     data: [210, 222, null, 222, 220, 210, 210, 210, 223, 210, 218, 225],
     color: 'blue',
     height: 5
   }, {
     name: '2018-RendimientoF',
     data: [null, 225, 225, 225, 225, 225, 235, 245, 225, 215, 215, 229],
     color: 'brown',
     lineWidth: 4
   }, {
     type: 'spline',
     name: '2018-Meta Core',
     data: [267, 267, 267, 267, 267, 267, 267, 267, 267, 267, 267, 267],
     marker: {
       lineWidth: 2,
       lineColor: 'red',
       fillColor: 'red',
       symbol: 'circle'
     },
     color: 'red'
   }, {
     type: 'spline',
     name: '2017-Meta Core',
     data: [220, 220, 220, 220, 220, 220, 220, 220, 220, 220, 220, 220],
     marker: {
       lineWidth: 2,
       lineColor: 'red',
       fillColor: 'red',
       symbol: 'circle'
     },
     color: 'red'
   }],

   responsive: {
     rules: [{
       condition: {
         maxWidth: 500
       },
       chartOptions: {
         legend: {
           layout: 'horizontal',
           align: 'center',
           verticalAlign: 'bottom'
         }
       }
     }]
   }

 });

function loadLabels(chart) { 
 chart.series.forEach(serie => {
   switch (serie.color) {
    case 'red':
      serie.points.forEach(point => {
      if (point.x == 0)
         chart.renderer.label(point.y, point.plotX + chart.plotLeft - 10, point.plotY + chart.plotTop - 22)
        .css({
            color: serie.color,
            'font-weight': 'bold'
        })
        .add();
   })
    break;
     case 'purple':
      serie.points.forEach(point => {
        let espacio = point.y > 267 ? -9 : 34;
         chart.renderer.label(point.y, point.plotX + chart.plotLeft - 10, point.plotY + chart.plotTop + espacio)
        .css({
            color: serie.color,
            'font-weight': 'bold'
        })
        .attr({
          'stroke-width': 100,
            rotation: -90
        })
        .add();
   })
    break;
     case 'green':
      serie.points.forEach(point => {
        let espacio = point.y > 267 ? -9 : 34;
         chart.renderer.label(point.y, point.plotX + chart.plotLeft - 10, point.plotY + chart.plotTop + espacio)
        .css({
            color: serie.color,
            'font-weight': 'bold'
        })
        .attr({
            rotation: -90  
        })
        .add();
   })
    break;
     case 'blue':
      serie.points.forEach(point => {
        let espacio = point.y > 220 ? -9 : 34;
         chart.renderer.label(point.y, point.plotX + chart.plotLeft - 10, point.plotY + chart.plotTop + espacio)
        .css({
            color: serie.color,
            'font-weight': 'bold'
        })
        .attr({
            rotation: -90  
        })
        .add();
   })
    break;
     case 'brown':
      serie.points.forEach(point => {
        let espacio = point.y > 220 ? -9 : 34;
         chart.renderer.label(point.y, point.plotX + chart.plotLeft - 10, point.plotY + chart.plotTop + espacio)
        .css({
            color: serie.color,
            'font-weight': 'bold'
        })
        .attr({
            rotation: -90  
        })
        .add();
   })
    break;
   }
 })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<div id="container" class="chart"></div>
```

El evento `load` se ejecuta luego de cargado gráfico, llamando a la función `loadLabels` que recorre las series e inserta las etiquetas (analizá esta parte del código para entenderlo). Lo primero que hago es identificar la serie a través del color (para mayor eficiencia podrías agregarle un `id` a la serie y switchearlas por este atributo), si la serie es red agrego la etiqueta solo en el primer punto (`point.x == 0`). Si la serie es purple o green, pregunto por el valor de cada punto (`point.y > 267`). Si es mayor, pongo la etiqueta por encima de la línea, si es menor por debajo. Para el caso de las series brown y blue la lógica es la misma solo que tomo como referencia el valor 220.

Como ves, así mismo algunas etiquetas se superponen. Yo aquí no puedo hacer más nada, queda en vos resolver que criterio utilizar en estos casos específicos.

Te dejo el script funcionando:
https://jsfiddle.net/ZottoSL/xdekn8h4/97/

Y la documentación sobre como cargar los labels dinamicamente:
https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#label

PD: Eliminé el atributo `plotOptions` ya que obviamente no es necesario.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda. Solo tengo una consulta, como a la gráfica le puedo hacer zoom, al hacerlo cambian de posición los indicadores pero los label se quedan donde se agregaron al inicio.¿Cómo puedo identificar que acabo de hacer zoom? así podria limpiar los label de posicion y volverlos a dibujar.

Comment: El evento `selection` es el que se ejecuta cuando haces zoom. Aqui la doc: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.selection. Igualmente durante la semana que viene veo si puedo ayudarte al respecto.